# SSIS - In DFT, how to each row input to exe and read the output for each row?

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

In the Data Flow Task, I need re-direct each row to exe and get the output for each row, similar to script component.

I tried to use Process in Script Component, but it is throwing exception "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.".
The code used in Script Component is:

```
 Process myApp = new Process();
 myApp.StartInfo.FileName = @"Someexe.exe";
 myApp.StartInfo.Arguments = "param1";
 myApp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 myApp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

 myApp.Start();
 while (!myApp.HasExited)
 {
  string result= myApp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  }
```

Any suggestions? I would like to know if there is any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is helpful:  "StandardOut has not been redirected..."   
Since you want to capture the output, redirecting it to the Destination Component, don't you want to change the line:

```
myApp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

to be:

```
myApp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Consider the example at this link, on BOL: 
 
[ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)